# Downloaded data in excel format using LWC in salesforce. When i open the file it shows warning prompt: File format and extension do not match

Tags: lightning-web-components, data-export, table, excel, format

[image: ScreenShot]

Hi,

Currently iam implementing functionality of downloading data using LWC  by using following code:

```
    let doc = '<table>';
    // Add styles for the table
    doc += '<style>';
    doc += 'table, th, td {';
    doc += '    border: 1px solid black;';
    doc += '    border-collapse: collapse;';
    doc += '}';          
    doc += '</style>';
    // Add all the Table Headers
    this.type1ReportColumnHeaders.forEach(element => {            
        doc += '<th>'+ element +'</th>'           
    });
    doc += '<tr>';
     doc += '</tr>';
      this.wsWSMMDdetails.forEach(record => {
        doc += '<td  align: center>'+record.normalCDD+'</td>';
        doc += '</tr>';
    });  
    var element = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(doc);
    let downloadElement = document.createElement('a');
    downloadElement.href = element;
    downloadElement.target = '_self';
    // use .csv as extension on below line if you want to export data as csv
    downloadElement.download = this.weatherStationName+'.xls';
    document.body.appendChild(downloadElement);
    downloadElement.click();
```

by using above code iam able to download the file but if open the downloaded file iam getting format issue alert as shown in the attachment.Plese suggest me what could be done or any workaround for this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://www.apexhours.com/export-to-csv-xls-using-lightning-web-component/
- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000UcLhQAK

Answer (score 0):

Use `.xls` instead of `.xlsx`, or use something like [js-xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-xlsx) to create a proper XLSX file.

Comment: Hey i want export html string data in excel format in lWC, Please let me know if there is a way...
Example HTML String is follows

  let doc = '<table>';
        // Add styles for the table
        doc += '<style>';
        doc += 'table, th, td {';
        doc += '    border: 1px solid black;';
        doc += '    border-collapse: collapse;';
        doc += '}';          
        doc += '</style>';
        // Add all the Table Headers
        doc += '<tr>';
        doc += '<th align="center" colspan="9">' + 'CINCINNATI' +' Weather Station' +'</th>'

Comment: @MuraliAS For the HTML format, use `.xls` instead of `.xlsx`.

Comment: if i use .xls, when opening the downloaded file shows format issue alert, is there possibility to convert html string to excel by using SheetJS (javascript library)?.

Comment: Can Someone help me in this.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/413881/export-html-string-in-excel-format-in-lwcsalesforce

Answer (score 0):

If you use [XL-Connector](https://www.xappex.com/xl-connector/) – it will pull data into Excel with zero issues, manually or automatically, and there's no need to write or maintain any code.